# Mapserver, TMS, Scales zoom levels and how to deal with all of it

Tags: coordinate-system, mapserver, scale, tilecache

I have a whole bunch of data in my db that I need to draw at different zoom levels using [Mapserver](http://mapserver.org/mapfile/layer.html). Everything uses a 4326 SRID. My (custom) client, will fetch the data using 20 TMS zoom levels and images of 256x256 pixels.

In fact, for every zoom level, these are the units-per-pixel that every zoom level uses:

```
<TileMap version="1.0.0" tilemapservice="http://myserver.com/cgi-bin/tilecache.cgi/1.0.0/">
<!-- Additional data: tms_type is default -->
<Title>myimagery</Title>
<Abstract/>
<SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
<BoundingBox minx="-180.000000" miny="-90.000000" maxx="180.000000" maxy="90.000000"/>
<Origin x="-180.000000" y="-90.000000"/>
<TileFormat width="256" height="256" mime-type="image/png" extension="png"/>
<TileSets>
  <TileSet href="http://myserver.com/1.0.0/myimagery/0" units-per-pixel="0.70312500000000000000" order="0"/>
  <TileSet href="http://myserver.com/1.0.0/myimagery/1" units-per-pixel="0.35156250000000000000" order="1"/>
  <TileSet href="http://myserver.com/cgi-bin/tilecache.cgi/1.0.0/myimagery/2" units-per-pixel="0.17578125000000000000" order="2"/>
  <TileSet href="http://myserver.com/cgi-bin/tilecache.cgi/1.0.0/myimagery/3" units-per-pixel="0.08789062500000000000" order="3"/>
  <TileSet href="http://myserver.com/cgi-bin/tilecache.cgi/1.0.0/myimagery/4" units-per-pixel="0.04394531250000000000" order="4"/>
  <TileSet href="http://myserver.com/cgi-bin/tilecache.cgi/1.0.0/myimagery/5" units-per-pixel="0.02197265625000000000" order="5"/>
  <TileSet href="http://myserver.com/cgi-bin/tilecache.cgi/1.0.0/myimagery/6" units-per-pixel="0.01098632812500000000" order="6"/>
  <TileSet href="http://myserver.com/cgi-bin/tilecache.cgi/1.0.0/myimagery/7" units-per-pixel="0.00549316406250000000" order="7"/>
  <TileSet href="http://myserver.com/cgi-bin/tilecache.cgi/1.0.0/myimagery/8" units-per-pixel="0.00274658203125000000" order="8"/>
  <TileSet href="http://myserver.com/cgi-bin/tilecache.cgi/1.0.0/myimagery/9" units-per-pixel="0.00137329101562500000" order="9"/>
  <TileSet href="http://myserver.com/cgi-bin/tilecache.cgi/1.0.0/myimagery/10" units-per-pixel="0.00068664550781250000" order="10"/>
  <TileSet href="http://myserver.com/cgi-bin/tilecache.cgi/1.0.0/myimagery/11" units-per-pixel="0.00034332275390625000" order="11"/>
  <TileSet href="http://myserver.com/cgi-bin/tilecache.cgi/1.0.0/myimagery/12" units-per-pixel="0.00017166137695312500" order="12"/>
  <TileSet href="http://myserver.com/cgi-bin/tilecache.cgi/1.0.0/myimagery/13" units-per-pixel="0.00008583068847656250" order="13"/>
  <TileSet href="http://myserver.com/cgi-bin/tilecache.cgi/1.0.0/myimagery/14" units-per-pixel="0.00004291534423828125" order="14"/>
  <TileSet href="http://myserver.com/cgi-bin/tilecache.cgi/1.0.0/myimagery/15" units-per-pixel="0.00002145767211914062" order="15"/>
  <TileSet href="http://myserver.com/cgi-bin/tilecache.cgi/1.0.0/myimagery/16" units-per-pixel="0.00001072883605957031" order="16"/>
  <TileSet href="http://myserver.com/cgi-bin/tilecache.cgi/1.0.0/myimagery/17" units-per-pixel="0.00000536441802978516" order="17"/>
  <TileSet href="http://myserver.com/cgi-bin/tilecache.cgi/1.0.0/myimagery/18" units-per-pixel="0.00000268220901489258" order="18"/>
  <TileSet href="http://myserver.com/cgi-bin/tilecache.cgi/1.0.0/myimagery/19" units-per-pixel="0.00000134110450744629" order="19"/>
 </TileSets>
</TileMap>
```

I am aware that, [depending on the projection I use, true scale changes differently](http://trac.mapnik.org/wiki/ScaleAndPpi). Some people have even [produced scale tables for WGS84 at different latitudes for 72DPI output, which is  very helpful to answer this question](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/FAQ#What_is_the_map_scale_for_a_particular_zoom_level_of_the_map.3F)... so the question is:

How are people dealing with this problem when they want to guarantee that some data is only drawn at a particular zoom level? This seems like such a basic question, but I am honestly curious. I guess I could arbitrarily pick MAXSCALEDENOM and MINSCALEDENOM scale values that are half way between the zoom levels.

So [using the table above](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/FAQ#What_is_the_map_scale_for_a_particular_zoom_level_of_the_map.3F), to guarantee that something should draw on level 13, but not level 14, I could say 1:40500, or * MAXSCALEDENOM 40500*. Is this right? It seems hacky :(

Comment: It looks like I may end up having to do my first bounty...

Comment: Why not use MAX/MINGEOWIDTH instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I can't speak for others, I use Geoserver and had much the same question when I started.  Unfortunately, I didn't find a particularly nice feeling solution to it either.

I used the Sld file to put in max and min zoom scales.  Same as what you have mentioned as seeming hacky, just choosing 1:40500 for a display betwen level 13 and 14.
For all levels I just went off [your link to the table](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/FAQ#What_is_the_map_scale_for_a_particular_zoom_level_of_the_map.3F) and picked something round inbetween.

It would be nicer in this situation to have a MaxLevel and MinLevel that then only renders between those levels, but I guess the scale calculations suffice for most.

Comment: It is what I ended up doing, too